# Failing to update kernel

Tags: linux

I have a Natty linux server with linux 2.6.18 in a VPS.

I wanted to install new software in it now when I realized Natty is not longer supported. So i changed the repositories to Oneiric (deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main restricted universe, etc.)

After solving many problems (I've been all the afternoon here) I realized some of the dependencies also needed a newer kernel. So I decided to upgrade the kernel to 3.0.0-32:

apt-get install linux-image

Here it failed. When it asked to me to update the grub thing, it said that it couldn't detect the file system of my storage device (/dev/vzfs) and now I got stuck here:

```
root@server1:/tmp# apt-get install linux-image
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 351 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic (3.0.0-32.51) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-32-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1. # <===== HERE
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-32-generic
Failed to create initrd image.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image:
 linux-image depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.0.0.32.36); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                 Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched everywhere, but couldn't find any answer. I even tried to find information about why does "fixrtc" fails, but there's not even documentation about what does it do or how it works...

Any idea?

Aditional info:

```
root@server1:/tmp# update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
unshare failed: Operation not permitted
Cannot find list of partitions!  (Try mounting /sys.)
done
```

Aparently the new kernel is installed and grub is able to find it. But I am really afraid of rebooting my server in case that grub will not work and boot my machine.

```
root@server1:/sys# mount
/dev/vzfs on / type vzfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
```

Eventhough my grub.cfg file in /boot/grub has:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio

        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-32-generic root=/dev/vzfs ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        insmod gzio

        echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-32-generic root=/dev/vzfs ro single nomodeset
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible.

I managed to get through that /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc by skipping this 'hook', setting this fixrtc as non-executable (chmod -x). But then it complained when he did the update-grub.

After a while, I realized that I had no kernel installed in my machine. Yes, I still can't understand at all how can a linux machine work without the linux core, but i think it's because the VPS thing.

My VPS is a Virtuozzo (as I could see by mount -> /dev/vzfs has a vzfs filesystem (not "normal" ones like ext3)), and from https://serverfault.com/questions/158323/no-grub-on-vps EEAA's answer it looks like I can't choose my kernel.

So I uninstalled the kernel and now /boot looks empty like it was before. Will just have to switch to another server (this one was too cheap to be good...)